# Как создать данную таблицу Html со стилями?

Tags: html, css

[image: Помогите создать таблицы]

Как создать таблицы с помощью тега thead tr и td?

Answer (score 5):

```css
table,
tbody,
thead,
th,
td {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

th {
  background: #bfefff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th></th>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
    <th>Header 4</th>
    <th>Header 5</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Line 1</th>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Line 2</th>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Line 3</th>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>23</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```